# state_machine gem Call Method Every Step Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

Using the gem `state_machine` how do you call a method every time the state changes? I read over the [documentation](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) and don't know whether I should use events or states, and how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533958/2016383) covers it quite thoroughly but let me just add some options to the list. These are equivalent:

```
state_machine do

  after_transition :your_method  # the most simple
  after_transition any => any, :do => :your_method  # state based
  after_transition :on => any, :do => :your_method  # event based

  # ...
end

def your_method
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Event is a transition from one state to another. Let's say you have a Car model and you want to implement 2 states that it can be in: `parked`, `in_motion`.

The possible transitions would be:

`start`:  `parked => in_motion`

`stop`:   `in_motion => parked`

And let's say, that before `start` transition you want some method called `fasten_seatbelt` to be executed and after `stop`: method `stop_engine`.

It this case, you should define these methods as callbacks, like this:

```
class Car
  ...
  state_machine :state, :initial => :parked do

    before_transition :on => :start, :do => :fasten_seatbelt
    after_transition :on => :stop, :do => :stop_engine

    event :start do
       transition :parked => :in_motion
    end

    event :stop do
       transition :in_motion => :parked
    end
  end
  ...

  private

  def fasten_seatbelt
    ...
  end

  def stop_engine
    ...
  end
end
```

Now, when car is in `parked` state:

```
 car.state #=> parked
```

You can call `start` method on it, simply like:

`car.start`

That would first call `fasten_seatbelt` method and afterwards change car's state to `in_motion` (`before_transition` callback for action `start` was defined).

When car is `in_motion` and you call `car.stop`, then it would first change state to `parked` and afterwards call `stop_engine` method (`after_transition` callback called).

Now if I understand you correctly, you would like to call the same method after every state change. If that is the case, then you should define callback in the following way:

`after_transition :on => any, :do => :your_method`

And define `your_method` for your class just like I did it with `fasten_seatbelt` & `stop_engine` in the example above.